# Comparing ASCII value of input (C Program)

Tags: c, comparison, ascii

For practice I am trying to create a program that counts the number of each digit, alphabetic character, and "whitespace" character in a line.

My program is printing fine however my counter is not correctly adding each character it reads.  Below is the code for the program (I've only started learning about a week ago so please excuse any glaring issues).

I believe the my main issue rests in the if/else if statements where I compare the int c to a variety of ASCII values.

```
/* Print Count of Each Char, Spaces, and Digits */

int main(void) {
    int c, i, CountWhitespace, count, Alpha;
    int CountCharacter[26];
    int CountDigits[10];

    CountWhitespace = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        CountDigits[i] = 0; }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        CountCharacter[i] = 0; }

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            ++CountDigits[c]; }
        else if (c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
            ++CountWhitespace; }
        else if (c >= 'a' || c <= 'z') {
            ++CountCharacter[( c - 'a')]; }
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            ++CountCharacter[(c - 'A')]; }
    }
    printf("Whitespace Characters: %d\n", CountWhitespace);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d appears %d times.\n", i, CountDigits[i]); }
    for (Alpha = 'a', count = 0; count < 26; count++, Alpha++) {
        printf("%c appears %d times.\n", Alpha, CountCharacter[count]); }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Below is an example of the output:

[image]

The green characters are the input, and as you may be able to tell, none of them are added to their corresponding variables.

Comment: What do you mean by 'main issue'? What exactly does not work?

Comment: make the changes Paul Roub suggested and it will work.

Comment: Issue has been resolved.  Thank you for the quick check and everyone's assistance.

Comment: eh,your second `else if` needs `&&` instead of `||` or otherwise it will be true always!

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes thank you for pointing it out, I had already made the edit, but it is noteworthy for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the digits counter:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
  ++CountDigits[c];
}
```

This will be increment `CountDigits[48]` (for `'0'`), etc. Not what you want. You've got it right for `a..z`; do the same here:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
  ++CountDigits[c - '0'];
}
```

Comment: @Gopi, question not posted by me.

Comment: I'm specifically not using it because I want to get better with the basic cooperators and if/else statements.  I'm following the book "The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition" and while I know those built in methods exist, I want to work on the basics first.

Comment: @Kaiser17 Cool makes sense ATB